# What is the modern way of creating devices files in /dev/?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, character-device

#### tl;dr

If I want my module do adhere to modern practices, should I create devices in `/dev/` via `mknod` in a shell script or via `class_create` and `device_create` C functions directly in the module source code? What are the advantages of one approach over the other?

#### In detail

In [Chapter 3](https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/linuxdrive3/book/ch03.pdf) of [*Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition*](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/), page 45 the function `register_chrdev_region` is presented as the function to use for registering a character device if the device numbers are known.

However, since device numbers unused today could become used by the kernel tomorrow, the usage of this function is discouraged almost immediately, page 46, in favor of `alloc_chrdev_region`, which allows a dynamic allocation of major numbers.

At this point, though, the authors make the point that one can't create device nodes in `/dev/` in advance because to create them the major number has to be known, and it isn't known before `alloc_chrdev_region` returns.

The presented solution is a `sh`ell script, which:

- loads the module with `insmod`,

  - which calls the module's init function,

    - which calls `alloc_chrdev_region`,

      - which results in a new device in `/proc/devices`,
- uses `awk` to extract the major number from that device,
- finally passes that major number to `mknod` to create device files in `/dev/` (the minor number is encoded in the name of the device files).

However, [*The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide*](https://sysprog21.github.io/lkmpg/) makes use of functions `class_create` and `device_create`, **I believe** to accomplish the same task.

What makes me nervous about it is that, despite the book
[being still updated nowawdays](https://github.com/sysprog21/lkmpg/commits/master), it has some aspect that makes it older than *Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition*.

For instance, it makes use of `register_chrdev`, even though it suggests preferring `register_chrdev_region` or `alloc_chrdev_region`, whereas  *Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition* is more categorical in calling `register_chrdev` **The Older Way**, relegating its explanation to barely more than half of page 57.

On the other hand, *The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide* is not the only source that I've found that uses `class_create` and `device_create` C functions, rather than `mknod` shell function, to create device files. [Here](https://olegkutkov.me/2018/03/14/simple-linux-character-device-driver/)'s another one, blog post written in early 2018.

So how are things meant to be done today?

Comment: Devices (and symlinks to devices) are create via udev, have a look at e.g. [this intro](https://www.linux.com/news/udev-introduction-device-management-modern-linux-system/).